# WPF MVVM Highlight a Column in a DataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I'm quite new to using the `DataGrid`, Im using MVVM and the WPF `DataGrid` and would like to know how to Highlight a whole column in a `DataGrid`. As of now the view and viewmodel are separated. The `DataGrid` in the View looks like:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
          Height="130" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="6,6,0,0" 
          Name="DataGrid" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="769"  
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable}" />
```

In the View Model the `DataTable` is populated and bound to the grid. My question is how do I highlight the cells in a column. Furthermore I will not know which column to highlight intill it is set.

Comment: 1. It is unclear **when** (the condition) to highlight the column.
2. Should column headers be highlighted?